# How do I run/execute .java code inside Cygwin?

Tags: java, cygwin

Essentially, I'd like to replace Eclipse and just use Cygwin, if that's possible. I've made sure that the `javac -version` command points to the folder containing my JDK.

To get started I created a `Main.java` inside an existing project in Eclipse, that just contains a `println` statement. However, inside Cygwin, when I go to the src folder containing this file and type `javac PrintlnFileName.java` there's a bit of a wait time and then nothing. Ideally, running that command would return the `println` statement like the Console in Eclipse would.

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to compile it with `javac`. Then run the code with `java`.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html

Answer (score 0):

this stack over flow question discusses using bash to run java program using the "java -cp" argument inside a shell file.